# Referencing Controllers

Tags: angularjs

I was not able to find in documentation if it is possible to reference a controller using a similar syntax to the one used to reference modules:

```
angular.module('App').controller('Ctrl');
```

That does not seem to work!

This is in angular 1.2

Answer (score 0):

Here is link to documentation http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

In paragraph with title "Adding Behavior to a Scope Object" you can see example how to use syntax like you gave above.

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('DoubleCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.double = function(value) { return value * 2; };
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="DoubleCtrl">
        Two times <input ng-model="num"> equals {{ double(num) }}
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't think I explained my issue correctly. I need to pass a controller to a service. I need a reference to this controller which exists on a different file. I don't want to require the file.

Comment: Do you need controller or scope of this controller ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are a lot of reasons to be creating controllers in services, other than for templating purposes, but of course you can!

You can use the `$controller` service to create instances of controllers on demand. If the controller requires a `$scope`, you'll have to pass it as a local: `$controller("MyController", { $scope: otherScope.$new() })`. AngularJS does the `$scope` bit for you when a controller is created internally.

See [$controller](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24controller) for (slightly) more details.